# Can't call contract function in Remix in Web3 provider mode, but it works in Javascript VM

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, blockchain, remix

A simple contract for addition, an error is reported when calling the function add  in Web3 provider mode:

"Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?

VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode."

But it works fine in JavaScript mode. The contract is as following:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0;

contract Calc {
     function add(uint a, uint b) public payable returns(uint) {
         return a + b;
     }  
}
```

---

I found out that if I use the pure modifier and  compile it using the version 0.4.24, it would work.:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0;  

contract Calc {
     function add(uint a, uint b) public view returns(uint) {  
         return a + b;
     }  
}
```

choose the compiler version 0.4.24,  then I can call the function add successfully. **Why** is that?

Comment: This question really confuses me, does anybody know why the error happens? Please help..

Comment: What is your target blockchain? ropsten, rinkeby or mainnet.

Comment: in your first function have you send any eth to call that function because with payable you need to send eth. And btw if you only want to return a value not doing something that change the state of the blockchain then you should use view or pure not payable